# I have an issue on mysql file 110.err (408GB)

Tags: mysql

There is a file "110.err" on /opt/lampp/var/mysql consume big storage data I don' know the purpose of this file and what I should do ?[Screenshot of size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsD8B.png)

Comment: this is your error log... The filename comes from `[hostname].err`

Answer (score 0):

Download the file, stop the server, delete the file, then restart the server. Truncating the file might be an option to download & review the file (because you cannot use "Notepad" or alike to open 408GB); the last few megabytes should suffice. For example, the last 10.000 lines:

```
tail -10000 ./110.err > ./110_mysqld.log
```

Comment: Download a file with 408GB it's a big file to download it xD

Comment: Just download it's `tail`. If you delete it without reviewing, it will continue to grow - therefore the reason _why_ it grows would be relevant.